# Why is my command giving wrong output?

Tags: awk

I m trying to output lines if col 1 has digit value , but its not working. My sample file doesn't have digit in col 1 so shouldnt awk return nothing in this case?

my code

```
awk -F 'BEGIN {OFS=FS}{ if ( ( $2 ~/aaa/ || $2 ~/bbb/ || $2~/ccc/) && $1 ~ "[[:digit:]]$")print}' file
```

cat file

```
8F3FTO|aaa|278346|
TYF98|bbb|89237|
YUG198|ccc|29834|
aljs23456|ccc|241298|
```

my code returns

```
aljs23456|ccc|241298
```

Comment: Do you REALLY want `$2 ~/aaa/` (`$2` contains a string matching the regexp `aaa`) or did you intend `$2 == "aaa"` (`$2` is exactly the string `aaa`)?

Comment: `aaa` is part of the whole string which I wanna match. so `$2 ~ /aaa/` is what I m using.

Comment: In that case YMMV depending on the actual characters involved. If you want to test for a substring regardless of which characters are present, that'd be `index($2,"aaa")`. If your strings definitely cannot contain any regexp metachars, e.g. if they're only alpha-numeric as in your example, then it doesn't matter though.

Comment: Regarding `$1 ~ "[[:digit:]]$"` - the regexp delimiter character is `/`, not `"` which is the string delimiter. When you use `"` in a regexp context you're defining a string **dynamic regexp** (as opposed to a regexp constant) which awk has to parse twice to turn it into a regexp and then use as a regexp - don't do that unless you **need** to do it for some reason as there are caveats. So `$1 ~ "[[:digit:]]$"` should be written as `$1 ~ /[[:digit:]]$/`, just like your other regexps. It still wont work as I'm just explaining the regexp syntax here, not correcting the semantics.

Comment: That code looks to be missing the argument to the `-F` option. Or, rather, it looks like it'd take the awk script as the field delimiter. At least `gawk` does accept it as such... If you don't get an error for that, it would take the _next argument_, `file` as the awk script, which would give probably be a reference to an unset variable, so always false, printing nothing; or might give a syntax error. Other than that, i.e. if we change that to `-F '|'` it looks to me it should basically work. (Disregarding code-golfing and optimizing.)

Answer (score 4):

Unless that's a copy-paste error, you didn't actually specify `|` as the field separator.  You should have used `-F'|'`.

Also, all four of your input lines have one or more digits in column 1.  They also contain non-digits in column 1.  If you want to match lines where $1 contains ONLY digits then use `^[[:digit:]]+$`.

BTW, you can optimise your script a lot.  e.g.

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS}; $2 ~ /aaa|bbb|ccc/ && $1 ~ "^[[:digit:]]+$"' file
```

You don't need `if` because awk statements generally take the form of `pattern {action}` (with either being optional).  An action without a pattern executes for all input lines, and a pattern without an action executes `print` for all matching lines (`print`  is the default action when a pattern evaluates as true, which is why the statement `1` is a complete statement AND a common idiomatic synonym for `{print}` - "1" evaluates as true, so the default action `print` is executed).

or, if you want exact matches on aaa, bbb, or ccc for $2 (i.e. so that it doesn't match things like `aaab` or `foocccbar`):

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS}; $2 ~ /^(aaa|bbb|ccc)$/ && $1 ~ "^[[:digit:]]+$"' file
```